# Chrome extensions, change value of variable before executing script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple chrome extension which on click inserts some text in Swedish in the DOM. Works fine. So whenever a user clicks the extension, the text in inserted.

Now I want to extend this a little bit. What I want to achieve:

**1) When the user clicks the extension the first time, a text in Swedish is inserted**

**2) When the user clicks a second time, a text in English is inserted instead**

So basically I want to "toggle" the language inserted between Swedish and English.

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "TextInserter",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "description": "Inserts text",
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {}
}
```

The code in background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: 'var toggle = true;' // How can I toggle this value?
}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'content.js'});
});
```

The code in content.js:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('description');

if (textarea && toggle) { // Is always true
  textarea.value="Hej";
} else if (textarea && !toggle) {
  textarea.value="Hello";
}

toggle = !toggle; // Change the value of toggle so next time text is inserted in other language
```

This of course doesn't work since I'm setting

```
var toggle = true;
```

in `background.js`.

How can I achieve this toggle effect?

Comment: `code: 'window.toggle = !window.toggle'`

Comment: That... was surprisingly straight forward. And working fine, thanks! If you write an answer with that info and deleting your comment I'll mark it as accepted.